# Get or create a polygon based on LatLong

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I am really new to google maps and need some help.

I am calling a 3rd party api that requires a polygon to return markers.

I am not sure how to do this. Basically I want to be able to pass in a LatLong and return a polygon based on the window size and zoom level.

Is this possible?

Thank you for your time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sounds like the app needs the bounds of the map viewport.

Look at [the documentation for the getBounds method](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference#Map) of the google.maps.Map class.